# Excel 2010 VBA: Runtime error 1004, Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, copy-paste

I had been running a cut and paste picture routine for some time and all of a sudden Excel starting giving me this run time error. It had been working fine for several days until now (no OS update or reboot, though I did try closing and reopening Excel to see if it helped). Stranger still, the script does a batch copy and paste.picture, the same range (with recalculated values) is copied and pasted 13 times and the error message pops up usually in the last loop or occasionally at some random point.

I looked up support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905164:
"This issue may occur if either of the following conditions is true:

```
The Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macro copies and pastes one whole row in an Excel 2003 workbook.
The Microsoft VBA macro copies and pastes a range of 2,516 rows or more rows in an Excel 2003 workbook."
```

However, I am copying a range of 12,12 cells, from A1 to L12 to be exact, not even close to an entire row. I have tried using range.offset, xldown, rannge(cells(1,1), cells(12,12)) but none of these helped.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

```
Sub PutPic(ByRef FN As String)


 Dim fname As String
 fname = "E:\Users\ABCD\Documents\EFGH\" & FN
 Worksheets(2).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(12, 12)).Select
 'Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:l12").Select
 Selection.Copy
 'Sheets("sheet2").Range("a1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(Link:=False).Select
 Selection.Name = "Pic"
 Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
 Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromMiddle

 Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    .Activate
    Set ChtObj = .ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 400, 400)
    ChtObj.Name = "PicFrame"
    ChtObj.Width = .Shapes("Pic").Width
    ChtObj.Height = .Shapes("Pic").Height

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Pic")).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("PicFrame").Activate
    ActiveChart.Paste

    ActiveChart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="png"
    ChtObj.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Pic")).Delete

 End With
End Sub
```

The sub with the looping routine, totally ordinary which feeds a filename to the subroutine.

```
Public Sub MainRun()
 Dim i, j, k As Long
 Dim NMG, NMB As String

 Dim FNGBSig As String
 Dim FNUnivSig As String
 Dim BatchStart, Batch As Long
 BatchStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(15, 1).Value + 1
 Batch = 13
 For i = BatchStart To BatchStart + Batch - 1

'Some calculations that refresh values in range A1:L12

FNGBSig = i & "GoodBad.png"

        PutPic FNGBSig

 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using.

Comment: Just use the top-left cell for the target. The remainder of the cells will paste in adjoining cells.

Comment: Also, after the error message (and going into debug), I could manually paste the picture.

Comment: Please revise your question to include the code which is raising the error. This sounds like it might be a buffer issue that could be resolved with a small delay.

Comment: That MS Support whitepaper was in regard to xl2003.

Comment: @Jeeped, I inserted .Range("A1").select before the paste picture line, but no difference

Comment: If you're calling this in a loop (13 times?) can you show the code that calls this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the loop is causing the issue as the `.Export` method is running in to itself. Use the WinAPI `Sleep` function to insert a small delay (1 second is probably enough).  Also, I've cleaned up the code a little bit:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For use in timer function

Sub PutPic(FN)

Dim fname As String
Dim shp As Picture
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

fname = "E:\Users\ABCD\Documents\EFGH\" & FN

'Copy the range of cells
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(12, 12)).Copy

    'Paste & get a handle on the resulting picture:
    Set shp = .Pictures.Paste(Link:=False)
End With

'Scale your picture:
With shp
    .ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromMiddle
End With

'Add the ChtObj frame:
Set ChtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 400, 400)
'Size the chart, paste the picture in the chart, export
With ChtObj
    .Width = shp.Width
    .Height = shp.Height
    shp.Copy
    Sleep 1000  '1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="png"
    .Delete
End With

shp.Delete

End Sub
```

Note that this is generally frowned upon:

```
 Dim i, j, k As Long
 Dim NMG, NMB As String

 Dim FNGBSig As String
 Dim FNUnivSig As String
 Dim BatchStart, Batch As Long
```

This declares `i as Variant, j as Variant, k as Long`, etc.  To do multiple declarations inline, you still need to specify the data type:

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long, k as Long
Dim NMG as String, NMB as String
' etc...
```

Comment: Thanks @davidzemens. Appreciate the guidance on bad practice too.

Comment: No worries, it is a common oversight :)

Comment: Sorry I have not yet been able to run your code, but will do that in a couple of hours. Your guidance on DIM actually helped resolved one other problem - I kept getting error with undeclared variables when calling subs and functions despite having done so. I did have to separate each of the variables into its own DIM. Now I see why what I was doing is frown upon!

Comment: your code work well with one change - Sleep was needed before the paste and does not appear to need it after export. I was able to get it down to 100ms without complaint. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user110084 yes I think you're right about the order of `Sleep` -- the issue is sometimes the `Paste` can execute before the `Copy` has finished, and that results in the error. The `Sleep` produces just enough delay to ensure that Copy has finished allocating to clipboard.

Comment: Overly optimistic unfortunately. It needed SLEEP 1200 in two more places! Before copy shp inside With ChtObj and before export. Otherwise, it exports an empty chart!

Comment: I finally got to the bottom of this behaviour. There is a dynamic name range in the native spreadsheet and it is updated in the background after each loop. As the range grew longer, it was taking longer to recalc the sheet. Removing the name range and moving the calculations on the sheet to VBA eliminated the problem. I kept SLEEP 200 in the code just in case.

Comment: Spoke too soon once again. It ran without issues for a while, but it started again after running around 7 to 8 batches (each batch has 13 loops with each calling the code above). I started increasing SLEEP (to 5000ms) but eventually even restarting Excel would not overcome it. A full PC reboot did though. What is happening? I tried using CMD to clear the clipboard, didn't help. Only a full PC reboot would do it.

Comment: Maybe try Application.CutCopyMode=False after the .Paste? Otherwise idk

Comment: Thank @davidzemens, I did insert the very line hoping that it would clear the clipboard and placed it just before the copy ahead of the offending paste. Very odd, not experienced this before with Excel. It would allow me to run in steps or even click run to continue except that it would export a blank file (not even blank chart) for that particular loop.