# Excel VBA: show line (outline) in chart object

Tags: excel, vba

Below is part of the code @davidzemens very kindly provided to my other [question on runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752664/excel-2010-vba-runtime-error-1004-microsoft-excel-cannot-paste-the-data). I would like to show the outline of the chartobject.

Is there a method I could use without having to name the chartobject (`ChtObj.Name = "ChartName"`), select and activate it and then using `ActiveSheet.Shapes("ChartName").Line.Visible = msoTrue`?

```
    'Add the ChtObj frame:
    Set ChtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 400, 400)
    'Size the chart, paste the picture in the chart, export
    With ChtObj
        .Width = shp.Width
        .Height = shp.Height
        shp.Copy
        Sleep 1000  '1000 milliseconds = 1 second
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="png"
        .Delete
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it; You have to use `.ShapeRange` property of your chart object (inside the `With ChtObj`), before you export:

```
With ChtObj
    .Width = shp.Width
    .Height = shp.Height
 ' here
    .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoTrue
 ' done
    shp.Copy
    Sleep 1000  '1000 milliseconds = 1 second
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="png"
    .Delete
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JChomel. Sorry about the original format. Need to read up on how to get links into the text.